# Transferring Object rigidbody properties (force, torque) and keeping them

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have given an inactive rigidbody the movement properties of an active rigidbody. in my program it is necessary to delete the active object and replace it with the inactive. when i do, the inactive object stops moving like the active.

```
    {
        inactive.SetActive(true);
        inactive.transform.position = new Vector3(active.transform.position.x + 7.9f, active.transform.position.y, active.transform.position.z);
        inactive.transform.rotation = new Quaternion(active.transform.rotation.x, active.transform.rotation.y, active.transform.rotation.z, active.transform.rotation.w);
        inactive.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddTorque(0, 0, -active.transform.eulerAngles.z * Time.deltaTime);
        inactive.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(active.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.x * Time.deltaTime, active.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.y * Time.deltaTime, active.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.z * Time.deltaTime);


        active.SetActive(false);

    }
```

it works fine if i take out

```
active.SetActive(false);
```

but i need the first object to be gone.

this code is in the late update method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't this work? 
Also, for physics, do it in FixedUpdate or in a coroutine after yield return WaitForFixedUpdate()

```
    inactive.transform.position = active.position;
    inactive.transform.rotation = active.rotation;
    inactive.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity=active.GetComponent<RigidBody>().velocity;

    inactive.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().angularVelocity=active.GetComponent<RigidBody>().angularVelocity;

    active.SetActive(false);
    inactive.SetActive(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution (thanks to zambari)

```
if (IsOutOfBounds(active))
{
    inactiveT.position = new Vector3(x,x,x);
    inactiveT.rotation = activeT.rotation;
    inactiveRB.velocity = new Vector3(x,x,x);
    inactiveRB.angularVelocity = activeRB.angularVelocity;

    activeSword.SetActive(false);
    inactiveSword.SetActive(true);
}
```